# mongodb on OSX : how to update brew service to start with auth?

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I installed mongodb with homebrew. I added an admin , and I updated the /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf to enable the security authorisation.

I can start mongod with auth:

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath   /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

But starting service :

```
brew services start mongodb
```

does not start with auth ...

how can I do it ?

thanks !!